# What are good words to use for "probably"?

Tags: разница

I understand that there are a variety of ways to say "probably," which depend on the context (my attempt at translation in parentheses):

```
вероятно (a bit literary, more in reference to likelihood)
наверно (more colloquial than above)
возможно (more in reference to a possibility)
скорее всего (implying something of the highest likelihood)
может быть (maybe, could be, can be)
пожалуй (seems more casual)
```

As a non-native speaker, should I default to using some of these words over others? Are these *generally* interchangeable, or is it confusing if one is said instead of another? Basically, it's hard for me to tell which is best to use in different contexts.

Comment: Correction: not *наверно* but *наверное* (though in casual speech it is pronounced as *наверно*). Yes, these are generally interchangeable. The best choice will always depend on the context (in the broad sense of the word).

Comment: There also is наверняка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all generally interchangeable. That said, you can divide them into groups:

**"Colloquial"** (наверно/наверное, может быть), which are mostly used in day-to-day speech (closer to "I guess" and "I think so");

**"Formal"** (вероятно, пожалуй), rarely used in speech, but often seen in articles (*вероятно* is more scientific, closer to "probably", and *пожалуй* is something you'd see in literature rather than hear in speech);

**"In-between"** (возможно, скорее всего) - *возможно* is quite close to "possibly", and *скорее всего* would be close to "It is likely that...", which you'd see in news.

Using these in a "correct" manner would require a lot of experience, so even if you use *вероятно* in a place where *наверно* would make more sense, you will simply sound more foreign - people will have no issue with understanding you.

Comment: I have the feeling that пожалуй means something more like "I suppose". Could be I'm wrong, I'm not native. What do you think?

Comment: Very colloquial:  "сдаётся мне". 

For example: "Сдаётся мне, мил человек, что ты сейчас по харе получишь."

Answer (score 3):

> Basically, it's hard for me to tell which is best to use in different contexts.

If you are almost sure, use `скорее всего`.

If you are not that sure, but chances are much higher than 50%, use `вероятно` (more formal) or `наверное` (less formal).

If you don't know if something is true, but it is possible, use `возможно` (more formal) or `может быть` (less formal).

Don't use `пожалуй`, as it has a special meaning.

Don't use the spelling `наверно`, since `наверное` is better.  `Наверно` instead of `наверное` is like `definately` instead of `definitely`.

Comment: "(pronounced without the final е) " - by whom? I never heard about this.

Comment: @Anixx - maybe I am wrong, so I edited this.